# Get Time for a page to load in asp c#

Tags: c#, web, time, response

I am a new user of asp and i was looking for a piece of code to test my page response time.
Is there any way to have a browser timer in order to know the exact time when a page finished to load and be displayed (for instance when refresh)?
A kind of google timeline but in a more simple way.
Thanks for your help

Comment: use jquery and print the time in a hidden field.. and chk by view source..

Comment: If you are usng asp.net mvc, [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) is an excellent choice.

Comment: you can use <%@ Page Trace="true" %> and check Trace details

Comment: @Hintham, no i am not using asp.net mvc, just using the classic asp the "empty web application"

Comment: @kyle yes, i have tried with the trace, the problem is that it is server side i think so i can't have the total time -> the client one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a hidden label and assign the page load time to it bu using Jquery easily.

```
$(function () {
    var beforeload = new Date().getTime();
    window.onload = gettimeload;
    function gettimeload() {
    var aftrload = new Date().getTime();
    // Time calculating in seconds
    time = (aftrload - beforeload) / 1000
    $("#lbltxt").text(time);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, so now I have the loading time. Do you have any idea of how can i get some more details such as rendering time ? Maybe I should look on google before. But if you have any idea to help it will be great.

Comment: @WilliamW IF u want to see all details i will recommend you to use tools like Firebug..So you can explore a lot.Its a great tool :) and my ans helps plz mark it as ans..For the sake off reputation,,,, :P

Comment: I will have a look of everything you gave me. Thanks for your fast answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

This stack question provides some useful answers on this topic, particularly the 2nd answer.

[Calculating Page Load Time In JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341156/calculating-page-load-time-in-javascript)