# How can we store time of js load with page load time?

Tags: javascript

Exaple:-

From this side you can see all information about over page.
http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/b9eJAg/www.google.com

How can we store for our all page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var timerStart = Date.now();
    </script>
    <!-- do all the stuff you need to do -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- put everything you need in here -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
             console.log("Time until DOMready: ", Date.now()-timerStart);
         });
         $(window).load(function() {
             console.log("Time until everything loaded: ", Date.now()-timerStart);
         });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Source:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/14343144/3185456