# how to execute a function after the page is loading is done in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I have an angularjs app. In the html page I call some REST services when the page is loading. I want to calculate the time taken in loading the page.

I found below code at [Calculating Page Load Time In JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341156/calculating-page-load-time-in-javascript):

```
window.onload = function () {
    var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd-window.performance.timing.navigationStart; 
    console.log('Page load time is '+ loadTime);
}
```

But it uses window.onload.

Which angularjs directive should I use to execute this logic after the page load is done.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18646795/5119765

Comment: What actually you want to perform? Do you want to do something once you get data from api?

Comment: @Abhinav I wanted to log the total time taken by the browser to load the page completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
//do it here
});
```