# How to calculate the page load time for angular JS application( single page application)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-mobile, ionic-framework

How to calculate the page load time programmatically for a angular JS (single page application)? I have used window.performance.timing for multi-page application, but it's not works properly for single page application. anybody help for track page load time on single page application? Please help.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can achieve that by using [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk) + Chrome DevTools. It will help you track your app performance.

***Update since the OP wanted to get page loading time programatically:***

A possible solution might be the one provided to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341156/calculating-page-load-time-in-javascript#answer-14343144).

You just have to get the current Date before loading any other scripts and get the date once the angular app hits the run phase. Then just subtract both dates and you get the loading time.

So, you will have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timerStart = Date.now();
</script>
```

And then in your main angular module:

```
angular.module('app', []).
    config(function() {
        // some code
    }).
    run(function($window) {
        console.log("Time until reaching run phase: ", Date.now() - $window.timerStart);
    });
```

Didn't test but it should work.

Comment: I need to implement that on programmatically :(.

Comment: Thanx for reply.  i put these on my location change success function. var pageLoadTime = Date.now() - $window.performance.timing.navigationStart;
may i believe this value as correct load time while location changes?.

Comment: Because I got these value before  ajax request completes.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to measure. If you want to get the time spent during a route change you can listen to `$locationChangeStart` and `$locationChangeSuccess` events and compare the two dates.

Comment: I also found out this [github repo](https://github.com/mendhak/angular-performance) that may be useful to you for further reading.