# Pure JavaScript with real track of how much % page is loaded loading screen

Tags: javascript, css, html, loading

I am searching for a way to create a Page Loading Screen like the ones that shows progress in digits.

But purely in JavaScript, no jquery..
I dont know how to get the percent of page loaded via JS. For the loading screen.

I would like to make a Loading screen without the use of jQuery, just pure old Vanilla JS.

Please someone help me.

Comment: You might wanna read these: 1. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/basics/ 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341156/calculating-page-load-time-in-javascript

Comment: This could vary in complexity, depending on what kind of content you want to load via said progress indication. Is it just JavaScript? or, any any file - like HTML, images, fonts, CSS, etc?

Comment: @argon I want to have the logic for it via JS and would Implement the Loading Screen with maybe html Css and all ..

Comment: Maybe this would work, I have not tried it though https://stackoverflow.com/a/14878493/5752311