# How to find load time of the website using python or javascript

Tags: javascript, python, load-time

I need to find the load time of a website that I am currently building. I have hosted the site locally. How can I find its load time using python or javascript? I tried the following code, but I think it is for response time.

```
from time import time
from urllib.request import urlopen

stream = urlopen('https://01c92730.ngrok.io/index.html')
cream = urlopen('https://01c92730.ngrok.io/Webpage.html')
start_time = time()
output = stream.read()
end_time = time()
stream.close()
print(round(end_time-start_time, 3))

start = time()
output = cream.read()
end = time()
cream.close()
print(round(end-start, 3))`
```

Comment: Did you try to use your web browser's developper tools ?

Comment: I want to find if I can do through coding

Comment: maybe looking for something like this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341156/calculating-page-load-time-in-javascript

Comment: I didn't get any output with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just put var start = Date.now() at the start of the page and (Date.now() - start) at the end of the page to get the loading time.**

Case 1# without loading a library

```
<doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var start = Date.now();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write("Page load time " + (Date.now() - start) + "  milliseconds");
        </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Output: Page load time 0 milliseconds(Sometimes 1 millisecond)

Case 2# loading jquery library

```
<doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var start = Date.now();
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write("Page load time " + (Date.now() - start) + "  milliseconds");
        </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Output: Page load time 24 milliseconds( sometimes 22,23)

Comment: Does this give load time or response time?

Comment: This gives loading time. Just put var start = Date.now() at the start of the page and (Date.now() - start) at the end of the page to get the loading time.

Comment: But the timer does not increase though all the contents are not loaded yet.

Comment: Have you tried the above two codes? Time increases when you load some external libraries.

Comment: What do you mean by external libraries?

Comment: Like in the example -2 in my answer, I have used **jquery library** to compute the load time.

Comment: I want the timer to increase itself until all the contents are loaded. But, with the above code, only a particular millisecond is given. Only when I reload the page then the time is changed.

Comment: Basically, the above code is measuring the time at the start of the loading and also the time at the end of the script and by subtracting the initial value from the end we can get out the result. It won't be that simple to make a timer that would increment the time while scanning the page data.